# Forgot admin password....Unable to select Utilities in Recovery Mode

Tags: password, administrator, ios

I have a MacBook Pro (mid 2009), which I haven’t used for a couple of years. I can start it and use it as I don’t have a log in password set up, but since I forgot my admin password, I’m now unable to install any new softwares, nor make any changes to it. I found a guidance on how to add a new admin password by starting the Mac in recover mode, but I can’t click on Utilities in order to select Terminal (where I can apparently set up a new admin password). I can use tab keys to move within the ‘OS X Utilities’ window, but I can’t get into the menu bar just above the window.

Comment: Ctrl/F2 [or Fn/Ctrl/F2] will access the menu bar, then arrow keys will navigate.

Comment: What @Tetsujin said or, when I'm navigating it I find it easier to use the numbers associated with the tabs